# Why is Lebesgue so often spelled "Lebesque"?

Tags: terminology, math-history, mathematicians

[Henri Lebesgue (1875-1941)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Lebesgue) was a French mathematician, best known for inventing the theory of measure and integration that bears his name.

As far as I know, "Lebesgue" is the correct spelling of his surname, but it seems to be [quite common](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=lebesque) for people to spell it "Lebesque", with a q.  Why is this?

- Is "Lebesque" somehow an acceptable variant spelling of "Lebesgue"?  (I don't really know much about French orthography.)
- Would "Lebesque" be pronounced similarly to "Lebesgue" in French?  (I don't know much about French pronunciation, either.)
- Was this an error made in some widely read book, which has thus infected many other people?
- Is it simply that the letters g and q have a similar shape in some scripts or typefaces?  I don't seem to see people  mixing up g and q very often in other contexts.

---

**Edit.** To look for further examples, I searched for "lebesque" on MathSciNet ([search results](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=TI&pg5=AUCN&pg6=AUCN&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=&s5=&s6=&s7=lebesque&s8=All&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=1&extend=1), subscription required).  There are 48 matches for the term, either in article/book titles or other metadata, or in reviews.

There seems to perhaps be a disproportionate number that are in Russian or other Eastern European languages.  Maybe there is something related to transliterations to/from Cyrillic?  They could also just be errors by the translator.

Many of them, however, turned out to be errors in the MR database.  For example, there is an item listed as "[Brown, Arlen. On the Lebesque convergence theorem. *Math. Nachr.* **23** 1961 141–148.](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=139716)", but when we go to [the article itself](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.1961.3210230302/abstract), as originally published, we see it was in fact spelled Lebesgue.  So this is probably an error introduced in data entry or perhaps OCR.

Worse yet: MathSciNet has an [entry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1555243) for a 1927 *Acta* paper by Lebesgue himself, under the author "Lebesque, Henri"!  And when we follow the link to the [article on SpringerLink](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02564114), we see that it is also spelled "Lebesque" in the SpringerLink database.  But if we download the original article itself, it is actually spelled Lebesgue.

I didn't check all of them, but there were a few that I was able to verify:

- Parfënov, O. G. Criteria of nuclearity of embedding operators acting between Bergman spaces and weighted Lebesque  spaces. *Math. Nachr.* 154 (1991), 105–115.  [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1138373) | [Journal](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/mana.19911540109/abstract)
- Abilov, V. A.; Pkhasy, S. The evaluation of the Lebesque function of Fourier-Jacobi double series.  Math. Balkanica (N.S.) 2 (1988), no. 2-3, 208–209. [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=981280) | [Article](http://www.math.bas.bg/infres/MathBalk/MB-02/MB-02-208-209.pdf)
- In *A Concise Introduction to the Theory of Integration* by Daniel W. Stroock, Chapter III is entitled "Lebesque Integration".  See the [table of contents](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/pdf/10.1142/9789814439183_fmatter). However, the titles of other chapters and sections use the spelling "Lebesgue", so this is probably just an unfortunate typo.

Comment: I have always assumed the last option you listed, but I'm interested to know the answer.

Comment: Have you seen the "Lebesque" spelling used in any professional publications? If all you have to go by is usage of "Lebesque" on MSE, then I would imagine the last scenario is most likely. I've never seen Henri's surname spelled with a *q*.

Comment: Writers of English encounter "que" more often than "gue", so when a w. of E. is unsure he might be inclined to opt for the more familiar triplet.  It might also be a muscle memory thing, in this age of "writing" meaning "typing".  The answers to your questions are No, No, Not that I know of, Maybe.  Have you ever seen the misspelling in a book or paper?

Comment: @JohnDawkins: That's a good guess.  I don't think I have seen it in print, so maybe it's just a common student error.  (Like all my students who I have to train not to pronounce "Euler" as "You-ler".)

Comment: When I first learned the name as an undergraduate, I also misremembered it's spelling as having a 'q.' Interesting psycholinguistic phenomenon.

Comment: Wait till you see Tcheb*tchev, a trademark of disgruntled graduate students in probabilistic number theory.

Comment: @JohnDawkins : I think it'd be harder to fool an entire referee committee, which explains why it hasn't gone to papers and articles yet...

Comment: @guest, it's pronounced TshebyshOv. His last name in Russian contains $\ddot e$, which is formally "o" softening the consonant before it; however, "sh" is never softened (we have a "shch" for this like in borshch). "y" is a hard "i".

Comment: To jump on this bandwagon, I've seen Weierstrass misspelled as Weierstrauss more than a few times, and I've heard numerous mathematicians pronounce Liouville as Louisville. Perhaps Americans are just not interested enough in learning correct spellings and pronunciations when it comes to French and German? :)

Comment: In Russian/Cyrillic it's spelled as [Лебег](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B3,_%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%80%D0%B8_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD), which would roughly transliterate as `Lebeg`. There is no q in Cyrillic, but 'г' corresponds to 'g' and, to the best of my knowledge nothing else. Thus it is unlikely that origin of this spelling is Russian.

Comment: @zespri The Russian spelling is rather accurate here with consonants (for vowels, at least the second `e` could be replaced by `э`).

Comment: Because several English words [end in *esque*](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/esque/), while none [end in *esgue*](http://www.wordfind.com/ends-with/esgue/).

Comment: It's the same reason Dutch people misspell *barbecue* as *barbeque*. Don't laugh, it happens all the time.

Comment: I once heard that the most common source of misspelling is similarity to existing words. For example, iridescent is often misspelled with two r's because of its similarity to other words like irradiate and irresponsible. I think the same phenomenon is at play here. "gue" almost never occurs in English, wherase "que" is quite common.

Comment: @Grumpy: My wordlist has 269 words ending in "que", and 231 ending in "gue" (analogue, fatigue, synagogue, tongue, vague, segue, rogue, plague, pedagogue, ...). Some of those are alternatively spelled "-og", especially in American English. Perhaps more tellingly though, it has 107 ending with "sque" and none ending with "sgue". The only ones that even contain "sgue" are "misguess" and its conjugates.

Comment: @SteveJessop: excellent. Hard data!

Comment: This question is more about Linguistics and not really about Mathematics at all.

Comment: Note that (at time of this comment) [your example](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=lebesque) gives 82 results for the incorrect "Lebesque", while [searching for the correct spelling](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=lebesgue) gives 8,598 results. The misspelling is not unheard of on this site, but relatively speaking I don't think it's common at all.

Comment: Maybe "quite common" is an overstatement, but in my personal experience, I see this misspelling much more than any other.

Comment: It doesn't help that another famous French mathematician, l'Hôpital, has multiple spelling variants of his name.

Comment: Could *Lebesque* exist as a variant of the surname *Lévêque*?

Comment: @anton-sherwood Yes, [Lebesque](http://www.123genealogie.com/nom-de-famille/lebesque.html) is a variant of Levesque and Lévêque. On the other hand, Lebesgue is a nickname designating a person who stutters (le bègue).

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh It should be noted though that a final `г` in a russian word is pronounced as a `k`, which results in `Лебег` being pronounced `lebeck`, closer to -que than to -gue.

Comment: @reinierpost, far from laughing, I think many native English speakers also misspell barbecue [that way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque/1433932#comment2922825_1433899) (else the universally accepted BBQ would not make any sense!).  Google Ngrams gives a [respectable showing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=barbeque%2Cbarbecue) for barbeque, although it's much less common than I would have thought.

Comment: @VerenaHaunschmid, discussions of spelling are always marvellous places to trip up.  I hope I may light-heartedly and without any malice intended note 'except' in place of 'accept' in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque/1433932#comment2925393_1433899).

Comment: Nate, I have fixed all appearances of Lebesque on this stackexchange site and on MO that can be fixed (i.e., not appearing in a comment) other than on one MO page and on this page.  Now it's your job to check every now and then for new appearances of Lebesque on this site and correct them. :)

Comment: @NateEldredge it has been 4 months since I systematically removed the appearances of Lebesque on MSE that are not on this page, and searching today I found 5-6 new ones!  They have all been fixed.

Comment: @NateEldredge today I discovered that Dover’s description of its edition of Kolmogorov and Fomin’s “Elements of the Theory of Functions and Functional Analysis” uses the phrase Lebesque interval. Ouch! See the Product Description tab on https://m.doverpublications.com/0486406830.html or the back cover on https://www.amazon.com/Elements-Functions-Functional-Analysis-Mathematics/dp/0486406830#immersive-view-vertical_1652957697499.

Answer (score 48):

I am also a native French speaker (from France) and I confirm that **Lebesgue** is the correct spelling and that Lebesque is just a bad typo from this site.

The situation is not that bad, however. As the OP pointed out, there are 82 users who misspelled his name, but if you search for "Lebesgue" on this site you will find 8,587 entries. So the ratio is less than 1%. By the way, I remember having corrected this typo at least once and I invite you to help me until the number of such misspellings reaches Lebesgue measure $0$....

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question (unless I am overlooking edits), since the question asks for reasons the name was misspelled.

Comment: Doesn't the number of misspells already have Lebesgue measure $0$? :-P

Comment: Ok, let's start cleaning it: http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Lebesque Nvm, they have to be "improved" by at least 6 characters.

Comment: Nevermind again, you can simply search for typos, grammar mistakes and improve wording. Three edits a day will make "Lebesque" go away.

Comment: we may succeed in making the set of such misspellings of Lebesgue measure $0$, but its *Lebesque* measure will remain positive.

Comment: Actually, all finite or countable sets have Lebesgue measure 0, so you achieve that goal even without editing anything.

Answer (score 33):

I think this is a good question, and as the edit makes clear, the scope of it is certainly larger than stackexchange websites.

I have wondered about this myself over the years.  Nate Eldredge's suggestions are as good as any I can come up with: in particular, yes, in older typefaces "Lebesgue" and "Lebesque" look very similar.  Especially, slightly shoddy typesetting can lead to the bottom portions of these characters being removed, so I think it is likely that there is at least one classic text in which one cannot properly read the name.  It would be interesting to find one.

I will mention what I think is one further ingredient: mathematics is decidedly less concerned with supplying source material (primary or otherwise) and in correctly associating ideas with names than most other academic fields.  This is true to a degree which is simply remarkable once you notice it.  For instance, a typical undergraduate mathematics textbook does not have a bibliography!  If results are attributed to specific people, it is people like Newton, Leibniz and Cauchy, and this being done to leaven the text with human interest stories.  (It is common enough to have a footnote giving a sentence or two of biographical information about someone like Cauchy.  Which is nice, but calls into stark relief the absence of actual bibliographic information.)

The most common amount of effort taken in tracking down the reference in which Theorem X.Y was actually proved is zero.  Rather, the association of a name to a result, when (too rarely) done in a mathematics textbook, is done entirely according to the author's whims.  This turns the association of names with results into a game of whisper down the lane played by textbook authors and their readers.

I will give another example, closer to my own heart.  For almost 20 years now I have been a fan of the [Chevalley-Warning Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevalley%E2%80%93Warning_theorem) (and recently a bit more than a fan, but if there is any relevance to that, it is just that in this case I *actually have read the primary literature*).  Now I have noticed over the years that about 5% of the mathematical world refers to this result as the "Chevalley-Waring Theorem".  I don't think there can be any good reason -- no one calls it that after their attention is drawn to Ewald Warning's 1936 paper on the subject -- and yet I have seen it in published papers.  Most recently I saw it in a review of my recent grant application.

> Finally the PI has a proposal concerning 'combinatorial nullstellensatze and Chevalley-Waring'. I read this section, but have insufficient expertise in this subject area to judge the importance of this proposal. I see that for instance the PI has generalizations of Waring's theorem (saying that a system of polynomial equations over a finite field of low degree compared to the number of variables, either has no solutions or has quite a lot of solutions) to rings of integers modulo prime powers. This seems quite striking to a non-expert.

I think this is interesting glimpse of the psychology involved.  Needless to say the grant application spoke of the "Chevalley-Warning Theorem".  Probably the reviewer was, like many number theorists, much more familiar with the mathematician Edward Waring than the mathematician Ewald Warning, so substitutes one for the other without noticing.  Or checking.  In fact the reviewer includes quotation marks around what is by no means a direct quote (for that matter in my grant application it says *Combinatorial Nullstellensätze*, not *combinatorial nullstellensatze*, so a German language error has also been introduced inside a direct quote).

I don't mean to be too hard on the reviewer, who *openly admitted* lack of expertise in the area.  They undoubtedly also had a lot of evaluative work to do in a short period of time, and getting the names of dead mathematicians right was not their priority.  But that's my point: as a profession, getting the names of dead mathematicians right is typically our lowest priority.  I think this is something to work on in the future, because it is so nicely enabled by modern technology.  Time was you'd need to make a trip to a mathematical library to convince yourself that it's Chevalley-Warning, not Chevalley-Waring.  Now, if you google Chevalley-Waring, it will show you instead results for Chevalley-Warning.  Things are not as hard as they used to be.

**P.S.**: It is interesting to read the 48 MathSciNet citations to "Lebesque".  In the reviews dating back to 1973, the mistake is always corrected in the title or remarked upon by the reviewer.  Before then this seems mostly not to happen, and sometimes it is even the reviewer who introduces the mistake, as e.g. in MR0253894 from 1969.  Here is an exception:
the review of MR0179321 from 1963 is

> Simples exercices sans difficulté et sans grand intérêt. (Le nom de Lebesgue est systématiquement estropié dans le titre et dans le texte.)

The second oldest use of "Lebesque" occurs in

> Lebesque, Henri
>   Sur la recherche des fonctions primitives. (French)
>   Acta Math. 49 (1927), no. 3-4, 245–262.

However a look at the original paper shows that the author's surname is spelled LEBESGUE (capitals in the original).

The oldest use of "Lebesque" comes from the oldest paper I have yet seen on MathSciNet:

> Lebesque, A.;
>   Intégration d'un système d'équations linéaires du ne ordre. (French)
>   J. Reine Angew. Math. 15 (1836), 185–190.

According to the first page of this paper, this author's name is indeed "Lebesque".  Anyway, [Lebesque is a real French surname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morvan_Lebesque).

**Final Irony**: Henri Lebesgue's father was a typesetter.

Comment: [This site](http://sites.mathdoc.fr/cgi-bin/rbsm?au=LEBESGUE) attributes the Lebesque paper you quote to a Lebesgue... but it does have a better (attempt at) typesetting the title itself.

Comment: @Mat: Interesting.  But here is the original article: https://eudml.org/doc/146958.  At the top of each page we find "Lebesque" and also "intégration", so one can see that the "q" and the "g" are quite typographically distinct.  So I guess the mistake goes in both directions.

Comment: When I first read Serre's "Course in Arithmetic" I manually crossed out the "n" in the title of the Chevalley-Warning theorem, so sure I was that it had to be Waring. At a later point in college or grad school I realized I made a mistake and manually put the "n" back in. A typographical error I have found myself making too often (but I think I have always caught myself) is Dedeking for Dedekind. Pete, has that happened to you?  On MathSciNet, "Dedeking" occurs only four times and always in a review. I'll write to MathSciNet and see if they would correct those.

Comment: Update: No more "Dedeking" on MathSciNet.  The number of hits there for "Lebesque" anywhere is now 45 rather than 48.

Answer (score 15):

1. I am a native French speaker, although not from France.
2. Lebesgue is definitely the correct spelling, and Lebesque sounds completely different; *besgue* sounds like *beg* in *to beg*, but the *qu* in *que* sounds like a *k* here.
3. I don’t know what you’re reading, but I have never seen it spelled like this in my life. I assume it comes from non-French speakers who remember the spelling wrong or mix up the letters, but as I have never seen the phenomenon myself, it’s hard to tell. (Maybe if you had an article or a text where it’s written? But then again....)

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you want some examples, follow [the link I gave](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=lebesque) where you can see 82 users of this site using that spelling.

Comment: Examples are one thing, correctness is something else. According to the french websites I have used in the past (being European, familiar with French, but most likely not as fluent as Patrick) I concur with him that the correct spelling is "Lebesgue". Just like the correct spelling of Gauss is not Gauss but the double s should be a "Scharfes S" that kind a looks like the beta from Greek. But mis-translations happens when you go from one language to another

Comment: @imranfat : I looked at 3-4 questions where Lebesque was written and they all look poorly written (not in the sense of the mathematical content but of the mastery of the language ; this is not to insult them, I learned German from scratch and I looked far worse at my beginnings, so things like this need to happen). I think it is fair enough to assume it's a spelling mistake of them, and just keep using Lebesgue. :D

Comment: @Did : sure, I just couldn't come up with it XD I was thinking of something that sounds like gone but has a gu in it... I guess in English the u is always somehow pronounced!

Comment: league, analogue, fatigue, tongue, brogue,...

Comment: Yes! Great examples.

Comment: But not "tongue" in British English. "Tongue" rhymes with "wrong," or "wrung" in the north of England. Listen to the audio at  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tongue.

Comment: I have _never_ heard "tongue" rhyming with "wrong". The pronunciation key at the page you cite very clearly indicates it rhymes with "wrung".

Comment: @imranfat: writing Gauß as Gauss is a matter of choice of orthography, though, we English-speakers are transliterating a character that we're not familiar with and can't be bothered to find on a keyboard. While it's arguably incorrect, it's frequently intentional, just as we transliterate Чебышёв to "Chebyshev" or some other version (in which case none of the letters appears in English orthography, so realistically we have no choice). Writing "Lebesgue" as "Lebesque" is simply a spelling error, albeit one that's apparently been made 82 times in the history of the site.

Comment: .. as for how you definitively tell the difference between a spelling error and a variant usage, ask ELU, but as a rule of thumb if the writer when questioned says "oops" and changes it, then it was a spelling error. And fortunately Gauß escaped the orthography reform of 1996 (since it's a long vowel), so at least the Germans aren't getting it deliberately wrong too ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop. So you got that Scharfes s on your keyboard of which I attached a picture here...) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#/media/File:German_typewriter_detail.jpg

Comment: It's all because French has too complicated spelling :D

Answer (score 5):

Words ending in "que" are much more common than words ending in "gue". See Latin. :-)

Comment: What does your answer contribute when there are already answers containing this information and more?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi What does your comment contribute?

Comment: @MarsOneRover Potentially decreasing the number of less-than-useful answers in the future? The bar for contribution of a comment is much lower than that of an answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "already". At the time I wrote that answer, it seemed there were no such answers.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi This is not an academic journal with limited publishing resources and the corresponding need for rigorous standards and bars. This is an internet forum that can and should accommodate the free expression of a variety of ideas and perspectives, subject to evaluation by the community—which, in fact, is provided via the upvote/downvote/comment system. Besides, I still prefer seeing even a thousand inferior answers on this forum to letting contribution policing foster an atmosphere of discouragement, doubt, and self-censorship.

Answer (score 5):

> *Why is Lebesgue so often spelled “Lebesque” ?*

Because “-esque” is a very common French suffix, corresponding to the English “-ish”. $($For instance, in Romanian, which is a Romance language, just like French, the equivalent “-escu” is extremely popular in family names$)$. So the confusion is quite understandable.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the comment by the OP that this is particularly common in articles from Eastern Europe points to a possible contributing source of the confusion. Namely, Russian, Polish, and a number of other Slavic languages (not to mention German) have something called "final consonant devoicing." A consequence of this is that at the end of a word, any *g* sound will be pronounced as *k*. So for someone having only heard the name, but not having looked particularly closely at how it is written, it may be tempting to write it as *Lebesque*, as if it ended in a $k$ sound, particularly if they are aware that *-esque* is a possible ending in French names, the most common such name probably being *Lévesque* (in which the *s* is silent, just as in *Lebesgue*).

Answer (score 3):

In the French language, [words ending in QUE](http://www.wordmine.info/Search.aspx?slang=fr&stype=words-ending-in&sword=QUE) (4503) are almost 10 times more common than [words ending in GUE](http://www.wordmine.info/Search.aspx?slang=fr&stype=words-ending-in&sword=GUE) (583). Furthermore, that same site counts 189 French words [ending in SQUE](http://www.wordmine.info/Search.aspx?slang=fr&stype=words-ending-in&sword=SQUE) and 0 [ending in SGUE](http://www.wordmine.info/Search.aspx?slang=fr&stype=words-ending-in&sword=SGUE).

Some people here have said that QUE is also more common in English, but the difference in English is much less marked (381-QUE vs 240-GUE).

Given that the name is indeed a French name I think it is natural to expect it to have the more common French ending, especially since many people may be familiar with the former French Canadian Prime Minister named René Lévesque.

Comment: The <s> in <Lebesgue> is silent. I suppose it would be spelt <Lebêgue> in modern French orthography.

Comment: @Zhen. I don't think that's relevant. The /s/ in Lévesque is also silent.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about there being zero words ending in SGUE. That wouldn't account for proper nouns.

Comment: Just a note, Lévesque was Quebec premiere, never Prime Minister.

Answer (score 2):

It might help to note that in French (and certainly among all of the dialects of French) that certain phonemes are very easy to confuse in casual speech and certain words could be written several ways phonetically if one was uncertain of the etymology.  Thus, someone unfamiliar with the name Lebesgue (the Stutterer) could confuse it with the name Lévesque (the Bishop) and write it with a "q" rather than a "g".  It's quite common for the same French surname to have several different possible spellings, but still one usually doesn't spell one's own name incorrectly.  The transformation from "g" to "q" probably happened later by someone unfamiliar with the etymology of the name and it stuck.

Also a note on the silent "s"s: it's a carryover from Old French in which the "s"s were pronounced and then lost in Middle French with a change in vowel quality but retained in the written language.  After some more significant shifts in pronunciation and spelling reforms, many of the silent "s"s were omitted in writing (especially in between syllables) but some still remain (particularly in the last syllable of a word).  In these two names the older spelling is retained and the "s" is silent.

Comment: Your comment that the last name Lebesgue is related to le bègue = the stutterer is interesting since Tartaglia (nickname for Niccolo Fontana), who found the solution of cubic equations, has a similar source related to his difficulty speaking: tartagliare = to stutter.

Answer (score 1):

here is what my guess on this is:

It could be from OCR or just typos during manual copy but we can't take out the fact that lowercase g in many fonts is very similar to q. Where g is like q with an extra returning arc at the bottom.

Windows fonts Arial, Century Gothic, Courier New and a bunch of other are good examples of what I mean

also Brush Script MT and some other handwriting variations have closely looking g and q.

Answer (score 1):

An aspect that hasn't been mentioned. The English way the cursive letter "q" is drawn is quite similar to the French "g". While there is no or little danger of confusion between "q" and "g" within the English or the French cursive alphabet, a mixed audience may actually misread "Lebesgue" from a blackboard.

http://janbrett.com/pdf/alphabet_tracers_q_cursive.pdf

*edit* In fact, to really answer the question, one should check *by whom* the name is misspelled. My educated guess is that whoever learned Lebesgue theory from *books* would almost surely write the name correctly. Unfortunately, many peolple do not go beyond class lectures or seminars, and copying from a blackboard the unknown name, "gue" is not just possibly   mistaken for "que", but very likely to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could also think of it as a kind of play on words, although I doubt many ever intended this. So "Lebesque" would be taking a prefix coming from "Lebesgue" and applying the adjectival "que" suffix, to mean "Lebesgue-like".

Comment: Lebesguesque, you mean? ;-)

Comment: This reminds me of hearing that the name Artin was originally from Armenia, where it was Artinian.  So if the common name ending -ian had not been removed when the ancestors of Emil Artin moved to Germany, we might today speak about artinianian modules.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw the spelling $^{\star}$Lebesque in my life, for what it’s worth. You’re saying it’s quite common—you may well have a deeper measure-theoretic literacy than I do. At any rate, the possibility of a mistake being common does not make it correct.

The correct spelling is “Lebesgue.” As for the pronunciation, if you’re a native speaker of English, try saying $$\textit{the beg}$$ first, and then change the initial consonant “th” to “l.” This gives you the almost exact native French pronunciation. (The incorrect form $^{\star}$Lebesque would be pronounced *the beck*, again after substituting “l” for “th,” in French.)

Comment: What does your answer contribute when there are already answers containing this information and more?

Comment: Wouldn't *Lebesque  contain an /s/ sound?

Comment: Not Lebesque, but there is a very famous French Canadian PM named Levesque.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That’s an interesting proposition. I would still think that if that actually were the accurate spelling, then the grapheme “s” would simply be serving as a “placeholder” indicating that the preceding “e” should be pronounced as an [open-mid front unrounded vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-mid_front_unrounded_vowel) /ɛ/. Alternatively, the spelling could be “$^{\star}$Lebêque,” the circumflex indicating both an omitted grapheme “s” and the openness of the preceding vowel (as is common in French orthography).

Comment: UPDATE, based on the comment by @Octopus: Yes, Levesque is indeed a common surname, and it is pronounced /ləvɛsk/. Another common surname is Levêque, pronunced /ləvɛk/. This difference suggests that Federico Poloni is actually right!

Comment: @triple_sec, I've never ever heard anybody pronounce the /s/ in René Lévesque.

Comment: @Octopus I stand corrected: the pronunciation of Levesque or Lévesque is /ləvɛk/ or /levɛk/, respectively. This actually seems to support the “placeholder conjecture” I put forth earlier.

Comment: After a quick google search, the result is not unanimous, but it looks like most French (and Francophone) sources prefer the version without /s/. See for instance https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vesque.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi It is my impression that none of the other answers had discussed the pronunciation differences between the correct spelling “Lebesgue” and the incorrect one “$^{\star}$Lebesque,” whereas the OP specifically sought answers as to this point as well. I do respect your opinion about the contributions of my answer, or lack thereof; nevertheless, others may share a different view. Indeed, a lively discussion has evolved involving two fellow commenters about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My grandmother was a Le Besque (two words) born in 1889. I have traced my family tree back to 1675 and have seen hundreds of original documents citing the correct spelling of Le Besque, most have been archived onto my hard drive. My family originates from in and around Lorient, Bretagne. 
Noted Le Besque’s are: Jean Le Besque - Legion of Honour, Napoleonic Wars, Henri Le Besque - mathematician, Morvan Le Besque - novelist.
I have also found misspellings of Lebesque, Lebesgue and Le Besq. The misspellings were written in Parish BDM records, though I was able to link them by cross referencing.

Comment: 'from a french speaker) Definitely not, no mathematician has the name Henri Le Besque. Here is the etymology of the name Le besque : https://www.geneanet.org/nom-de-famille/BESQUE where they say it comes from celtic "besk" = shortened, whereas Le besgue designate a stutterer.