# motivation behind the notation $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis

let $\ell^\infty$ be set of all bounded real sequences, why we use this notation $\ell^\infty$? inparticular $\ell$. when i suppose x to be an infinite sequence i feel need to write it an element of $R^{\infty}$ but i dont write so beacuse there must be some very particular reason for using $\ell^\infty$. One thing in my mind is boundedness but How boundedness is related to notation $\ell^\infty$

Comment: Probably the 'l' comes from the name Lebesgue, from the $L^p$ spaces

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking about. Are you asking why is the $\ell$ symbol used, as opposed to $n$, $f$ or something or about the meaning of $\ell^\infty$ or what?

Comment: I am asking both

Comment: You can minimize number of texts in title. This seems more ;). "l" is enough in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $1 \leq p < \infty$, we may define the $p$-norm of a sequence $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots)$ of real or complex numbers, to be
$$ \lVert x \rVert_p = (|x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \cdots)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
when the expression makes sense (i.e. the series on the right is convergent), and infinity otherwise. The space $\ell^p$ is then defined to be all sequences of numbers having finite $p$-norm. For example, an element $x$ of $\ell^1$ is precisely a sequence whose series $\sum_i x_i$ is absolutely convergent. An element of $\ell^2$ is what is called a "square-summable" sequence, and so on.

It is natural to wonder what $\ell^p$ is in the limit $p \to \infty$ (and if this makes sense). It turns out that in the limit, we have
$$ \lim_{p \to \infty} \lVert x \rVert_p = \sup(|x_1|, |x_2|, \ldots) $$
where the expression on the right is called the "supremum norm" of $x$, which is finite if and only if the sequence $x$ is bounded. And so the space $\ell^\infty$ consists exactly of bounded sequences.

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_countably_infinite_dimensions_and_.E2.84.93.E2.80.89p_spaces) for $L_p$ space has a good overview of this. If you would like details on the proof of this limit, check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326172/the-l-infty-norm-is-equal-to-the-limit-of-the-lp-norms) for them.

Comment: Thanks. now I understand the reason behind use of $\infty$. But what is the reason behind use of letter $\ell$

Comment: The $L_p$ and $\ell^p$ spaces are named in honour of [Henri Lebesgue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henri_Lebesgue), who played a key role in the development of measure theory.

Comment: Yes. Because norm in $L_{p}$ involves Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @Bernard: [Ha!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1433899/why-is-lebesgue-so-often-spelled-lebesque)

Comment: It is Lebesgue for the counting measure.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge (or Roy Eldridge?;o)). I didn't even imagine such a typo was possible!